# goto url using javascript on Select box | DropDown box

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I have the below javascript function to go to the selected box value url.

```
function go(x) {
    alert(x);
    location = x.value;
}
```

I cannot use getElementById 
There may be more than 1 select box as the user differs
I wrote a php to print  all the selectbox inside a form and div

```
<div class="styled-select">
    <form name="menu">
        <select id=Admission onchange=go(this)>
            <option value=/admission>Add Existing Students</option>
        </select> 
        <select id=Student onchange=go(this)>
            <option value=www.bing.com>Student Details</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

You don't access the value of the element properly. Use this instead:

```
function go(x) {
    location = x.options[x.selectedIndex].value;
}
```

You also won't get an `onchange` event for a `<select>` with only a single option ever.

Comment: If this was the answer you needed, please mark it as Accepted!